# Downloading and adding ios 5 simulator to the xcode 4.5 and monotouch without xcode components

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

I want to download and install ios simulator 5 on my xcode and monotouch. I know that we can add it from xcode components by installing ios simulator 5 or 5.1 but my these days my internet connection is crazy :( it disconnect, also is very also on the xcode component.

Do any body have a link for download the emulator manually and add it to the xcode and mono-touch offline?

Comment: I was in the same situation ended up using download manager to get the file as it allowed me to pause download and continue after

Comment: Can you please explain more? How can I use download manager to download it? As I know xcode components just allow online installation and just by using it. I have not any stand alont links for simulator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't think there a direct link for Xcode components for a safe alternative approach install [DownThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/?src=search) in Firefox or [download master](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/download-master/mcceagdollnkjlogmdckgjakjapmkdjf) in Chrome.

goto [apple developer site](https://developer.apple.com/downloads) and search for Xcode 4.3.3 for Lion which includes iOS 5.1 SDK.

Use one of the download manger and sit back until it completed. open up the ISO file and navigate to:

```
Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs
```

copy folder in the following directory and then restart Xcode:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk
```