# How to download each version of iOS Simulator with direct link in XCode

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode5

I need to download iOS5 Simulator in my `XCode5`.

my internet connection is bad and can't download from `XCodes > Downloads.`

Is there anyways to download from direct links and how to install manually?

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct link to download it, I don't see why you cannot download it from XCode/Preferences/Downloads, I can.

Anyway, there's a user here explaining a little trick that may work:

[Downloading and adding ios 5 simulator to the xcode 4.5 and monotouch without xcode components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643236/downloading-and-adding-ios-5-simulator-to-the-xcode-4-5-and-monotouch-without-xc)

Answer (score 0):

There's no official way to add the `iOS simulators` lesser than 5.0. That seem to come to the conclusion that you cannot. The 4.3 simulator(per say) is no longer available but you can still set the deployment target, but you have to test on real devices.